# Passing Variables From File-to-File in C#

Tags: file, variables, c#

How would I use a variable declared in `Program.cs` and access it's value from `Form1.cs`?

I know how to do this in C, but I'm completely lost in Microsoft's little twist on C.

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using LuaInterface;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static Lua lua = null;
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            lua = new Lua();
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using LuaInterface;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lua.DoString("print('hi')");
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# is most certainly not a "twist on C". And I assume you mean passing parameters between the two classes? Or between two programs?

Comment: There are multiple approaches. Could you please post some of your code?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what I'm talking about when it comes to C#, as you can see. I guess that's what I'm saying, if the two classes are in two seprate files.

Comment: As an aside, it is very difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve without some code samples.

Comment: C# is object-oriented, not file-oriented. Stating your problem in OOP terms would help clarify your aim.

Comment: Files have nothing to do with, well, really anything in C#. Placing two classes in the same file is no different at all than placing them in two different files.

Comment: I have posted some code, you might notice I'm having some problems with editing the post.

Comment: Fixed and posted the code, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers. You guys explained it very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your examples of `Program.cs` and `Form1.cs` and assuming these are the default names and that you have a `Program` class that instantiates a `Form1` class and that you want to pass a parameter to the `Form1` class, you can do the following:

Define a constructor for `Form1` that takes this parameter and chain to the default constructor:

```
private Lua lua;

public Form1(Lua lua) : this()
{
   this.lua = lua;
}
```

In your `Program` class when instantiating `Form1`, pass the parameter to it:

```
lua = new Lua();
Application.Run(new Form1(lua));
```

Note that I am using OOP terminology - objects and classes (not files).

---

Update:

Since you have declared your `lua` variable as a public static member of the `Program` class, you *can* access it anywhere in your program (assuming the namespaces have been declared appropriately) as follows:

```
Program.lua;
```

Though you would want to instantiate the static field *before* calling `Application.Run`.

In any way, this makes the object a public shared resource across all threads - making it virtually untestable and difficult to work with if you go multi-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the parameter with

```
Program.lua;
```

But Oded's way is cleaner.

And in Main, the object must be instantiated before Application.Run:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        lua = new Lua();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Program.cs there is most probably a static class defined like this:

```
static class Program
{
   ...
}
```

If you declare the variable as `public` or `internal`, you will be able to access it from your form.

```
static class Program
{
    public static int myVariable;
    public static int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In your form, you access the variable and the property with:

```
int i = Program.myVariable;
int j = Program.MyProperty;
```

In object-oriented programming, you would usually keep the variables private and only declare the properties as public.

Comment: A static class has static variables.